# crontab for calling python script

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Ive been trying to get crontab to work all day but I think Im doing something wrong because it wont work.

So I have this script which im using to test whether the cronjobs run or not
and the script is named **crontest.py**

```py
with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Testing!')
```

So I make a cronjob

```
* * * * * python3 crontest.py
```

This should mean that every minute the script gets executed but nothing happens.

I think it might be because Im not providing a path for the script but I made sure that the script is in the home directory and python3 should be found as it is a system executable.

Comment: I would provide both the full path to the `python3` executable as well as the full path to the `crontest.py`. No reason to hope and pray that it's going to be able to divine both of them. `* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/youruser/crontest.py`.

Comment: First standard cronjob troubleshooting step is to capture output & errors from the job by adding something like `>>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` to the crontab entry. Let it try to run, then see what's in the log file.

Comment: ```* * * * * usr/bin/python3 home/crontest.py >>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1``` Should it look like this?

Comment: @jgore077 That's missing the leading `/` on `/usr` and `/home`. The `/` at the beginning of a path makes it absolute rather than relative, so you can't leave it off (or add one) without changing the path's meaning. The crontab entry should be more like `* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/youruser/crontest.py >>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` (with`/home/youruser/crontest.py` replaced by the actual path to the script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when working in crontab you have always to use absolute path, either for things inside the script that for script path.

In your case the python code must be changend like this:

```
with open('/path/to/test.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Testing!')
```

and also the crontab entry must be like this:

```
*/1 * * * * python3 /path/of/crontest.py
```

if you have trouble understing how to set crontab timing you can use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru)

Comment: I tried this and its still not working             ```with open('/home/james/test.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('testing') ``` and the crontab looks like this ```* * * * * usr/bin/python3 /home/james/crontest.py```

Comment: Are you sure `*/1` is necessary ? It should be the same as `*`.